# Applying worksheet_change code to original selection

Tags: vba, excel, comments

I have a code that adds comments to the selected cell whenever it is edited or its contents are deleted (something like "Edited/Deleted on 1/19/18 at 3:00PM"). I disabled the return key from moving the selection down, since the comment gets added to the new selection (below the cell). However, if you edit the cell and press any of the directional keys or tab or even select any other cell with the cursor the comment gets added there.

Is there any way to restrict that to the original cell that was modified?

Comment: Show us your code. The `Target` parameter gets the cell that was changed, so I guess you are using the `ActiveCell` or `Selection`, which is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vacip has noted, the `Target` gives you the cell that has changed, and you can then use the `OffSet` parameter of this to put the comment where you need it.

For example, `Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Foo"` would put the "Foo" in one row down from the cell that was changed while `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Bar"` would put "Bar" one column to the right.

Be sure to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the top of the procedure and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the bottom. This will prevent the procedure from activating the code again (which could potentially cause a nearly infinite loop until it runs out of columns.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. I was using "selection" for my range. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should do it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'enable events to false to restrict the code to one row below and not an infinite loop
    Target.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Edited/Deleted on " & Now()
    'add the Edited/Deleted text and date and time
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    're-enable events after doing what you wanted.
End Sub
```